# After installing Ubuntu 16 alongside Ubuntu 14, system not asking to select OS to load

Tags: 14.04, boot, 16.04, dual-boot, grub2

I have Ubuntu 14.04 already installed but needed to install Ubuntu 16 on another partition. The installation went smoothly but when I boot now I don't get an option to boot Ubuntu 14 or Ubuntu 16, and my system always boots Ubuntu 14.

When I tried to find the reason behind this I found that the partition on which Ubuntu 16 is installed is not mounted when system start.

Even after editing `fstab` to mount the drive, GRUB is still not showing up

How can I make my system ask me OS to boot?

Comment: You don't see option for 16 but you do see the grub menu?

Comment: No I don't get grub menu too, system directly starts in ubuntu 14

Comment: That should give you the option to choose, comment if it's still not showing the option

Comment: Ok I am installing the grub-customizer and will update the result

Comment: @Zanna, yes the partition was not mounted, but even after editing fstab there was no grub menu appearing. but Sumeet's solution did the trick and now the issue is solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Grub Customizer

To do that, Open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and enter the following commands one by one

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

After installing it open it and enable the option **Show grub menu on startup**

Comment: Bull's eye, worked perfectly as expected, Many thanks Sumeet.

Comment: You're always welcome